# Q3DScatter - Axis Orientaiton

Tags: qt, data-visualization

I'm using Q3Dscatter to plot a QCustom3DVolume, by default the Y-axis is vertical in the Q3DScatter, however I would like the Z-axis to be oriented vertically to match a hardware configuration I am using.

I can easily rotate the QCustom3DVolume, but this appears to be independent of the axes on the Q3DScatter object. The result is that scaling and positioning operations become messy and cumbersome, as they are performed on the  prior to rotation.

Is anyone aware of a method of reorienting the Q3DScatter axes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find an answer for your question? (I'm also interesting in it how to operate on axis of Q3Dscatter)

Comment: Nothing particularly elegant or satisfying. I ended up creating a kind of wrapper in which I could declare the orientation of the axis and the data would just be reinterpreted accordingly.

Comment: Thanks I will do it in similar way. Asked because want to append this feature to plotter tool that I wrote - https://github.com/burlachenkok/plotter_plusplus